# IndexError: string index out of range in Python code

Tags: python

There is an error in my code help me to correct it

This is the actual code

```
message=input("enter the message ") 
alphabet='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ' 
key=5 
encrypt='' 
for i in message:
   position=alphabet.find(i) 
   newposition=key+position 
   encrypt+=alphabet[newposition] 
   print(encrypt)
```

this is the error

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: message=input("enter the message ")
alphabet='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '
key=5
encrypt=''
for i in message:
    position=alphabet.find(i)
    newposition=key+position
    encrypt+=alphabet[newposition]
print(encrypt)

Comment: this is the code

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs when you enter a `w` `x`, `y`, `z` or `space`. `position` has the value `26` when `find` has found a `space`. Now you add `5` to your `position` which result in `31` and your string `alphabet` has only a length of `27`.
So you have to rework the line

```
newposition=key+position
```

to get a valid number between `0` and `26`. This can be done with `modulo` (or `%`) for example. You should convert the input string to lower case (or upper case and replacing your `alphabet` with upper case letter). Otherwise `find` doesn´t find any letter in your `alphabet`:

```
message="This is a test"
alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
key=5
encrypt=""
for i in message.lower(): 
  position=alphabet.find(i)
  newposition=(key+position) % len(alphabet)
  encrypt+=alphabet[newposition]
  print(encrypt)
```

Which results in

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Jul  9 2019, 00:06:43)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
y
ym
ymn
ymnx
ymnxf
ymnxfn
ymnxfnx
ymnxfnxf
ymnxfnxff
ymnxfnxfff
ymnxfnxfffy
ymnxfnxfffyj
ymnxfnxfffyjx
ymnxfnxfffyjxy
```

Comment: you should switch 26 to `len(alphabet)`, its 27 actually

Comment: @Kampi, the error will occur for ```w, x, y and z``` as well

Comment: @Sid yes I was updating my text just in this moment :).

Comment: another drawback to handle, uppercased letters: `for i in message.lower():`

Comment: I add it too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you have `w`, `x`, `y`, z or a (blank) in your input. Their positions in the  string are 22, 23, 24, 25 and 26.  respectively.Last position in `alphabet` is 26. `22 + 5 = 27`, which is out of range, thus the error. Same for x, y, z and , which will give 28, 29, 30 and 31 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem happens when

```
newposition = key + position
```

is larger than the length of your `alphabet`.

You can remedy your problem using [*modular arithmetic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)

```
newposition = (key + position) % len(alphabet)
```